# What's the best way to enhance website security in inspect element?

Tags: html, web-inspector, inspector, code-security

Is there a way for prevent any user from editing my html code from UI using inspect element ? I have done research there's many why to prevent inspect element ( or Right-Click ) but seems not all of them are effective .

So my question is how to prevent the user from editing my HTML Code using inspect element and what's more suggestion I can add to enhance website security?

Comment: Do you have a specific example where you'd need security on the front-end?

Comment: @ShamPooSham i'm taking about in general what can be enhanced in security side for my HTML code

Comment: It's HTML. Why does it need security?

Comment: @Duaa I have a hard time seeing where this would be useful, that's why I'm asking for a concrete example. If you don't want a user to see a specific element for example, you need to block it on the back-end instead of hiding it in the HTML. But maybe there's another case than hiding elements that you're thinking about

Answer (score 1):

You are going off on a tangent. No there is no way to prevent a user from editing content they have downloaded to their computer. But they are not editing your website - the website security is not being compromised.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to completely block inspect element.

You can try to prevent amateur users from doing it by blocking the context menu that shows up on right click.

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Users will not be able to access this:

[image]

It is completely normal to view a website's **frontend** HTML code.

As long as you use good **backend** practices, there will be no security issues.

Comment: Thanks !! but could you please add a picture of context menu you are taking about ? just to make sure I understand it right

Comment: The context menu is the menu that shows up on a page when you right click

Comment: @Duaa Sure, I attached a screenshot to my answer.